# creating slideshow in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, slideshow

I am trying to create a slideshow with `Java Swing`. 
I began with implementing a class `PicturePanel`

```
public class PicturePanel extends JPanel {

private int counter = 0;
private ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[10];
private JLabel label;


public PicturePanel()
{

for(int i = 0 ; i <images.length;i++)
{
images[counter] = new ImageIcon("check.png");
label = new JLabel();
add(label);
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new TimerListener());
}

}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

    public TimerListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        counter++;
        //counter% =images.length;
        label.setIcon(images[counter]);

    }
}
}
```

Then I am calling this class in my `Jframe` through this code :

```
panProfil= new PicturePanel();
```

`panProfil` is a `Jpanel` in my form

When I run my project, I don't get any errors, but there is nothing in my form. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you start your `Timer` ?

Comment: No I didn't, where should I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

So you haven't started your `Timer` that's the problem (as @ItachiUchiha pointed out). But another thing you need to do is know when to `stop()` the `Timer` or else it will keep running

You want to `start()` it in the constructor after you create the `Timer`. In you `ActionListener`, to stop it, you'll want to do something like this.

```
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (counter == images.length) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        } else {
            label.setIcon(images[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to access the `Timer` from your main GUI class, so you can control it, you want to have a `getter` for it, and declare it globally

```
public class PicturePanel extends JPanel {
    private Timer timer = null;

    public PicturePanel() {
        timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
    }

    public Timer getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }
}
```

Then you can start and stop it from your main GUI class

```
DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
Timer timer = panel.getTimer();
```

---

Also, I don't see the point of create a `JLabel` every iteration and adding it to the `JPanel`. You only need one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Project2 {
    int c=0;
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame login = new JFrame("Login"); 
        // creating a new frame
        login.setSize(700, 500);
        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel pic = new JLabel();

        Project2 p2= new Project2();

        String[] list = {"C:\\Users\\divyatapadia\\Desktop\\pic1.jpg", "C:\\Users\\divyatapadia\\Desktop\\benefit.PNG" , "C:\\Users\\divyatapadia\\Desktop\\pic2.jpg"};
        pic.setBounds(40, 30, 500, 300);
        JButton log = new JButton("SHOW");ImageIcon[] img  = new ImageIcon[3];
        for(int time = 0;time<3;time++) {
            img[time]= new ImageIcon(list[time]);
            }
        addPanel.add(pic);
        addPanel.add(log);
        login.add(addPanel);
        login.setVisible(true);
        try {
            log.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Timer t  ;
                     t= new Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                if(p2.c<3) {


                                    pic.setIcon(img[p2.c]);
                                    p2.c++;
                                    }}


                            });
                     t.start();
                 }
}
);

}catch(Exception ex)
 {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());

}

    }
}
```

Comment: Explanation please

Comment: if we want to show slide show of images on the basis of time  then one cane use this code. It is incorporated on eclipse ide using java language.

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60312806/edit) the post please

Comment: images will be shown in JLabel. On button click the slide show will start

Comment: why and at what place?

Comment: Click this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60312806/edit)